# Consolidating mutliple SharePoint web applications to one

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, upgrade

We are doing a 2010 to 2013 upgrade.  We have 9 webapps currently which we plan to consolidate down to 1 and use HNSC.  Since each of those webapps have a root site collection what happens when the content db is attached to the new webapp?

If I attach one content DB, move the root site collection to a HNSC, then attach the second content DB, will the root site collection of the second content DB become the root of the web app it attached to?

Answer (score 0):

Easy and fool proof method to migrate the path based Site collection to HSNC, use the Backup and restore method of SharePoint. It is lengthy but still works.

- Backup the site collection.
- you can lock the old site or delete it.
- Restore the site collection as a host-named site collection

You dont need to bring the content DB( detaching or attaching), in this way you will not get the conflict of the root site collections.

root site collection always path based, so if you convert it to HSNC then if you attach another DB then root site collection from that db will show up.

[Migrating Host-Named Site Collections](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/12/19/migrating-host-named-site-collections.aspx)

[Moving Path Based to Host Named Site Collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/09/09/moving-path-based-to-host-named-site-collections.aspx)